# Generating a script to delete a list of files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file containing a list of paths I want to delete.

Adding `rm` in front of each path (to generate a script that will run these deletions) seems like the obvious approach. How can I do this?

Comment: re: "could you please give me a response ASAP" -- this actually **does not** help you get responses faster. See http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#urgent

Comment: start from here `for row in $(cat file); rm $row; done`. It's tricky if there are spaces in your rows...

Comment: @Oerd, that's broken for more than just spaces -- it'll expand globs too. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for the best-practices way to iterate over a file, which `$(cat file)` isn't. (And then there's the lack of quoting in expanding `$row`, which creates its own bugs; and then there's the inefficiency of invoking the external `rm` command once per file, which `xargs` avoids).

Comment: @Oerd, ...also see entry #1 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: thanks @Charles for pointing that out, have read the link more than once, just never could get my head around `xargs` properly :) great answer btw!

Answer (score 6):

Changing a list of filenames into a shell script by prepending `rm` to the beginning of each line is dangerous practice: Filenames may not map to themselves when interpreted by a shell, and may even have side effects that include running arbitrary commands. Don't do that.

---

If you want to delete all files named in a file, just use `xargs` to directly invoke `rm` with the filenames passed:

```
xargs rm -f -- <input-file
```

Note that this will have xargs attempt to interpret escape characters, quotes, etc. inside the names; if you don't want this, and have GNU xargs:

```
xargs -d $'\n' rm -f -- <input-file
```

Similarly, if you had control over your input file's format, you should use a NUL-delimited stream of filenames rather than a newline-delimited list of names. (This is because POSIX filesystems allow newline literals inside filenames). If your input file is null-delimited, then you can use:

```
xargs -0 rm -f -- <null-delimimted-input-file
```

---

If you **really** want to generate a shell script that will delete a listed set of names, by the way, you *can* do this in bash, like so:

```
while IFS= read -r filename; do
  printf 'rm -f -- %q\n' "$filename"
done <input-list >output-script
```

Using `printf %q` escapes content in such a way that when reread by bash, it will be parsed as its literal contents (thus, putting backslashes before characters like `*` or `$` which might otherwise be interpreted).

That said, because this invokes `rm` once per file, it will be less efficient than `xargs` (which passes multiple filenames to each `rm` invocation).

---

That said -- there actually *is* a middle ground: You can have `xargs` invoke bash, and generated a safely quoted list in the latter, with only a minimal number of invocations:

```
{
  echo "#!/bin/bash"
  xargs bash -c 'printf "rm -f -- "; printf "%q " "$@"; printf "\n"'
} <input-file >output-script
```

Comment: @keda, the `--` ensures that all further options are treated as positional; if your file has a line containing `-r`, you want to delete a file named `-r`, not to modify other deletions to be recursive.

Comment: @keda, ...see Guideline 10 in the POSIX utility conventions at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use `sed`

```
sed 's/^/rm /' foo.sh > foo2.sh
```

`^` is the beginning of a line, so a start of each line will be replaced by `rm`.

Comment: This is true, but to do this and then run the resulting script would be very bad practice, incurring substantial security risk if the names are uncontrolled: What if one of them contains `$(rm -rf /)`, or even just a `*` with spaces around it?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree, but this is an answer to the posted question.  I didn't want to make any assumptions about @Ismail Shaik 's code.  In general, `rm` is a dangerous command not to be taken lightly.  My answer provided basic information and should be enough to get him going.  He should be responsible for making sure it is safe.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy However, I agree with you.  Precautions must be taken before executing any mass `rm` commands.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This was the first thing that poped into my head.  It was quick and dirty but it works.  You answer is more extensive and eventually safer.  Now he has two methods to choose from.  I learned something new.  Thanks!